# xpath match without "complicated expressions"

Tags: xml, xpath

Assuming the following XML

```
<project>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am attempting to select the node `<version>4.10</version>` that belongs to `junit`.

I have succeeded in selecting the element using an xpath tester, using the expression:

```
/project/dependencies/dependency/artifactId[text()='junit']/../version
```

however, it appears the library I am using does not recognize the `..` parent selector.

I've also tried

```
/project/dependencies/dependency/artifactId[text()='junit']/following-sibling::version
```

which worked for my tester as well, but again, this is a complicated expression (hence the `following-sibling::`).

Is there a way I can accomplish selecting this element using simple*r* expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the predicate a step earlier: `/project/dependencies/dependency[artifactId = 'junit']/version`.

Comment: this looks promising.. ran into another issue when trying to implement this.. i'll keep you up to date.

Comment: worked awesomely.. actually figured out it was due to namespacing :)